# Почему поле формы для загрузки файлов принимает не более 1 файла? Yii2

Tags: yii2

Всем доброго времени суток!
Не работает множественная загрузка файлов , а именно нельзя выбрать более одного файла. Редко задаю вопросы, всегда стараюсь сам найти причину, но тут уже не выдержал. Помогите пжлст люди добрые :)) (И не очень добрые тоже помогите) .
Приклепляю поле ActiveForm с загрузкой файла. Повторюсь, проблема в том что нельзя выбрать более одного файла, новый выбранный заменяет предыдущий, что вроде бы как странно ибо multiple в true; Кстати проблема НЕ не только с расширением но и со стандартным "fileInput";

```
<?= $form->field($fileModel, 'images[]')->widget(BootstrapFileInput::className(), [
'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*', 'multiple' => true],
'clientOptions' => [
    'previewFileType' => 'text',
    'browseClass' => 'btn btn-success',
    'uploadClass' => 'btn btn-info',
    'removeClass' => 'btn btn-danger',
    'removeIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> '
]
```

]) ?>

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы забыли Передать *ActiveForm* **'multipart/form-data'**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
```